# Create report from dotnet-counters collect output

Tags: .net, dotnet-counters

Is there a tool to visualize recorded counters (from dotnet-counters collect).
On prem we use prometheus and grafana to collect and vizualize counters, but this is not an option in this case since we do not have access to the environment and can only export a collect-output.